# Russian books on Fourier Series

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, book-recommendation

Russians are known on having very strong literature in Mathematics and Sciences overall. So as I am willing to improve my knowledge and problem solving in real-analysis, especially in Fourier series, so I wonder what are the books written and used by the Russians( I have a somewhat good level in Russian)?

Comment: see here https://books.google.de/books/about/Fourier_Series.html?id=XqqNDQeLfAkC&redir_esc=y i hope this will help you

Comment: Ok, I just saw that Dr Graubner has already posted Tolstov's book which comes as no surprise given its status. Sorry for that.. At least I hope the other two will be of some interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of my head I would recommend Georgi Tolstov's ["Fourier Series"](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4472942/) (1960 or 1962 version) which is also available in [English](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BXU509W) but rather easy to find in Russian as well. 
It provides for a very smooth and elegant introduction to the topic as far as my experience allows me to say. Descriptive and very well balanced. In any case it is considered a classic.

Another choice would be Anatolyi Aksionov's ["Mathematical Analysis. Fourier Series"](http://www.e-reading.club/book.php?book=133593) which is rather short (~90 pages) and part of a series on textbooks on analysis by the same author. I have not read it though.

A book on the topic written by a Russian, but in English (and perhaps the most recent one covering both of these "conditions") is Alexander Koldobsky's ["Fourier Analysis In Convex Geometry"](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Mathematical-Monographs-Alexander-Koldobsky-2005-05-01/dp/B01JXMMPT4/ref=asap_bc?ie=UTF8) which is certainly more specialised and focuses on the application of Fourier analytic methods in solving the Busemann-Petty problem (for more on this check [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35468/widely-accepted-mathematical-results-that-were-later-shown-wrong)).

Answer (score 2):

I hope it can help you :

Season $6-7$ of volume $3$ of  The fundamentals of mathematical analysis by Grigorii Fichtenholz

фихтенгольц - курс дифференциального и интегрального исчисления том 3:

[original language book](http://ikfia.ysn.ru/images/doc/mat_analiz/Fihtengolc_t3_1966ru.pdf)

author: [Фихтенгольц, Григорий Михайлович](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%86,_%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)